# method clash from android LoaderManager

Tags: android, classloader

Suppose I have an android app with a `Feed` class, which is called by some `Fragment` implemented as follows and throwing : `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.newsfeeder.ui.MainFragment cannot be cast to android.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks`

```
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements   LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Feed>>
{   
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_container, null);
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, (android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Object>) this);

        return v;
    } 
public Loader<List<Feed>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        final List<Feed> initialItems = items;
        return new ThrowableLoader<List<Feed>>(getActivity(), items) {

            @Override
            public List<Feed> loadData() throws Exception {
                try {
                    if(getActivity() != null) {
                        return serviceProvider.getFeeds(); //some method fetching some `feeds`
                    } else {
                        return Collections.emptyList();
                    }

                } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                    Activity activity = getActivity();
                    if (activity != null)
                        activity.finish();
                    return initialItems;
                }
            }
        };
    }

protected List<Feed> items = Collections.emptyList();
```

Btw `ThrowableLoader` class is implemented as follow

```
import android.content.Context;
    public abstract class ThrowableLoader<D> extends AsyncLoader<D> {


        private final D data;

        private Exception exception;

        /**
         * Create loader for context and seeded with initial data
         *
         * @param context
         * @param data
         */
        public ThrowableLoader(Context context, D data) {
            super(context);

            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public D loadInBackground() {
            exception = null;
            try {
                return loadData();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Ln.d(e, "Exception loading data");
                exception = e;
                return data;
            }
        }

        /**
         * @return exception
         */
        public Exception getException() {
            return exception;
        }

        /**
         * Clear the stored exception and return it
         *
         * @return exception
         */
        public Exception clearException() {
            final Exception throwable = exception;
            exception = null;
            return throwable;
        }

        /**
         * Load data
         *
         * @return data
         * @throws Exception
         */
        public abstract D loadData() throws Exception;
    }

and here's the `AsyncLoader`


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader; 
public abstract class AsyncLoader<D> extends AsyncTaskLoader<D> {
    private D data;

    /**
     * Create async loader
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public AsyncLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverResult(D data) {
        if (isReset())
            // An async query came in while the loader is stopped
            return;

        this.data = data;

        super.deliverResult(data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        if (data != null)
            deliverResult(data);

        if (takeContentChanged() || data == null)
            forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStopLoading() {
        // Attempt to cancel the current load task if possible.
        cancelLoad();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReset() {
        super.onReset();

        // Ensure the loader is stopped
        onStopLoading();

        data = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of your "AsyncLoader"?

Comment: Can you also show the imports?

Comment: I still miss the part where you call "LoaderManager.initLoader". Are you using there the support library's "LoaderManager"?. Take into account you need to use the support "FragmentActivity" and "Fragment" classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are mixing `android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager` with `android.app.LoaderManager`.

I guess you want to use the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) and hence you're using the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` class (those imports are missing), therefore you should not do the `((android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Object>)this)` cast but just implement the `android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Feed>>` interface in your `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and pass it without cast.